# Problema al borrar datos de una tabla! No me cumple WHERE

Tags: php, mysql

tengo este problema: al eliminarle un curso a un alumno debo borrar también los pagos pendientes de ese curso, esos pagos pendientes pertenecen a un alumno. El problema es que me esta borrando hasta los pagos con condición de pagado, y estos no los puedo eliminar porque los necesito para reportes de ingresos.

Estas son las tablas de las cuales borro los datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De la tabla inscritos, elimino la inscripción, y de la tabla pagos_estudiantes elimino las filas en donde el estado del pago sea igual a cero, osea los pagos pendientes. Pero resulta que me esta eliminando hasta los pagos con condición de pagado.

Si es de importancia, en la relación de las tablas tengo un DELETE ON CASCADE.

Esta es la función en la que hago el DELETE:

```
function eliminando_curso_student()
{
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root', '' , 'academia');

$id = $_GET['id'];
$query = "DELETE FROM inscritos WHERE id = '$id'";
$sql = $mysqli->query($query);

if($sql>0):
$query2 = "DELETE FROM pagos_estudiantes WHERE id_inscripcion = '$id' AND 
estado = 0";
$sql2 = $mysqli->query($query2);
echo '<script type="text/javascript">javascript:history.back()</script>';
else:
echo mysqli_error($mysqli);
endif;
}
```

Me borra la inscripción del curso bien, pero cuando va a borrar los pagos pendientes, borra hasta los que están en condición de pagado. Ayuda por favor

Comment: Cambia `estado == 0` por `estado = 0`

Comment: Cuando comparas en MYSQL no necesitas poner 2 "==" solo basta con 1

Comment: Cierro como error tipografico porque conoce la sintaxis de las asignaciones pero puso `==` por error.

Comment: SI es importante! como esta definido el delete en cascada??? es muy probable que ese este borrando todo!

Comment: Ah, pero espera, tienes relacionadas ambas tablas?, entonces ahora se entiende lo que está sucediendo. Si la tabla pagos_estudiantes está relacionada con la tabla inscritos por el id del alumno, entonces al borrar el id de la tabla inscrito vas a tener dos opciones, o se rompe la relación y el delete falla o simplemente está en cascada y está borrando todos los datos de la tabla pagos_estudiantes (para mantener integridad referencial)

Comment: no, cambiando el orden le va a borrar todos los pagos tambien! esto es un claro ejemplo de porque no hay que poner logica de negocio dentro de la base de datos...

Comment: Ah, sí, hablé mal, habría que borrarlo sólo de la tabla de pagos, no estudiantes

Comment: Hay un problema mas grave aca.. si borras el inscripto, como sabes quien hizo el pago? los clientes nunca se borran.. si es necesario se desactivan, si no vas a tener pagos que no sabes quienes hicieron. hay un problema grave de diseño en esta idea

Comment: Entonces me sugieres @gbianchi que elimine solo los datos de la tabla pagos, y para que no me salga la inscripción de ese alumno en ese curso puedo colocar un campo bool llamado activo y cuando me elimine esos pagos pendientes que lo pase a inactivo.. Que tan viable es esa idea?

Comment: esa podria ser una idea valida. Salvo que quieras saber que pagos no recibiste por estar dados de baja. no conozco tus requerimientos como para saber si con eso alcanza, pero eso es mas logico...

Comment: Igual asi mismo, si el usuario tiene pagos atrasados, deberias igual cobrarselos, entonces por ahi no alcanza solo con un booleano, si no tambien la fecha de baja.

Comment: A ver si termine de entender: En lo que presione eliminar curso debo eliminar los pagos que esten pendientes donde el id de la inscripción sea igual al id que recibo, y luego hacer un UPDATE en la tabla inscritos del campo activo = 1 pasarlo a activo = 0. Y lo de los pagos atrasados podria manejarlo asi: en el DELETE condiciona que borre los que tengan el estado = 0 y los que la fecha_a_pagar sea < a la fecha actual.. Si esa es lo solución correcta @gbianchi o la mas acorde hazmelo saber. Gracias

Comment: Por cierto @gbianchi puedo seguir dejando el DELETE ON CASCADE entre tablas?

Comment: yo no estoy de acuerdo en que la base maneje las relaciones entre las tablas.. pero esa es mi opinion solamente.. para evitar cosas como esta que te paso. y lo de los pagos, borrarias los pagos futuros.. los menores quedan sin importar si se pago o no.

Comment: @AlejoMendoza He podido observar que todo los temas están basadas a una plataforma de estuidos online, será que puedo observar tu proyecto, no hace mucho hicimos un proyecto de aquello y estamos trabajando en uno nuevo proyecto de plataformas de estudios online, quizás pueda ayudarte en algo en tu proyecto es para universidad o es un proyecto personal o de estudios.

Comment: Saludos J.Doe es un sistema para una academia de alta cocina, es un sistema de control de pagos, ademas de que cumpla con todas las condiciones de una escuela, inscripciones, horarios, retiros, etc.. De que manera puedo mostrartelo, estoy trabajandolo en local.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un error de sintaxis en la `query2`:

```
$query2 = "DELETE FROM pagos_estudiantes WHERE id_inscripcion = '$id' AND 
estado == 0";
```

Tienes que poner solo 1 '=' en vez de 2:

```
$query2 = "DELETE FROM pagos_estudiantes WHERE id_inscripcion = '$id' AND 
    estado = 0";
```

Comment: Saludos, igualmente con el estado = 0 me elimina todos los pagos de ese alumno, los pendientes que estan en 0 y los pagados que estan en 1. No se que estara pasando el AND no lo esta cumpliendo.

Comment: @AlejoMendoza hay algún trigger en tu tabla?

Comment: Pero estas seguro que en la tabla pagos_estudiantes tienes estudiantes que tienen estado diferente de 0? porque si no tienes pudiese parecer que estas borrando todos los pagos los registros.

Answer (score 0):

La sintaxis correcta es con un solo "="

```
DELETE FROM pagos_estudiantes WHERE id_inscripcion = '$id' AND estado = 0;
```

No obstante no olvides escapar tus datos para evitar sql injection.

Comment: Hola Guille, procura no responder publicaciones identicas a las ya publicadas. La parte de inyeccion de sql es interesante pero bien podria ser un comentario bajo la respuesta de Marc. Un saludo

Comment: queria que quede recalcado y se vea ese punto, pero acepto la correción. gracias!